# Using public static IP to access Docker container

Tags: docker, centos8

I am running an HAProxy container in CentOS Docker and mapped port 80 and 443.

A public static IP bind to my CentOS 8 machine, How can I use public static IP to access my HAProxy container?

The internal IP address can access the HAProxy container successfully and "curl localhost" can get the result I want.

However, if I curl the public IP or type the public IP on the browser I will get a connection timeout.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  haproxy:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
```

Added http and https to firewall

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I found the problem, it is because the cloud firewall is not set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have firewalld enable, if this is true you need allow access.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Sorry, I have done this part already, I will add this back to my content.

Comment: mmmm sometimes selinux is the reason, for example when you install nginx in the host you need create a policy to allow access. Could try connect but using selinux in permissive mode ( ```setenforce 0```)?